# Deploying a BizTalk Application Project (.btaproj) without the VSTS Task

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, deployment, biztalk

I have a BizTalk solution where a BizTalk Application Project (.btaproj) was configured for deployment following this tutorial [Step 1: Add the BizTalk Server Application project in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/feature-pack-add-application-project)

Problem comes due to the fact that, as far as I understand, the kind of package generated with this project is deployable with a Task which is only available for Azure Devops Services ([Deploy BizTalk Application](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-biztalk.deploy-biztalk-application)) and our environment is on premise (TFS 2017)

Any way of deploy this packages without this task? (PowerShell, MSBuild, MSDeploy,...)

P.S: I´m aware of the existence of BTDF, but this solution was configured with the .btaproj and I would like to avoid changing deployment project to .btdfproj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to avoid changing deployment project

Unfortunately, you kinda stuck.  BTAP is for TFS deployment, which I recommend you avoid and few, if any, shops actually use.

For on premise deployment, BTDF is the option to use.  BTDF doesn't take too long to integrate into your Solution and is worth the effort if you regularly deploy updates.